# Move the dynamically created buttons in clockwise using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some `input type=button` which are created dynamically using JavaScript. Here I need to shift those clockwise while click on button. Here is my code:

```html
<!-- Enter your HTML code here -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Buttons Grid</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="btns" style="width:75%;">
        </div>
        <script>
            for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
                var index=i+1;
                var element = document.createElement("input");
                element.type = "button";
                element.value = index;
                element.id = "btn"+index;
                element.setAttribute("style","width:30%;height:48px;font-size:24px");
                var foo = document.getElementById("btns");
                //Append the element in page (in span).  
                foo.appendChild(element);
            }
            document.getElementById("btn5").onclick=function(){
                
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I need when user will click one `button 5` the buttons present around `button5` will move clockwise means `button4` will shift to first place without changing its ids.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far to achieve this ? This sounds like a complex issue and nobody will make that work for you for free :)

Comment: your question not clear what are you trying to active

Comment: You can find a lot of solutions in [Discussions](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-buttons-container/forum)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
let container = document.querySelector("#btns");
container.insertBefore(container.lastElementChild, container.firstElementChild);
// or this ?
// container.appendChild(container.firstElementChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't need to create the buttons in js. You can create in html code. And just play with innertext of btns. My approach was like this;

```
btn5.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const textofBtn = btn1.innerText;
  btn1.innerText = btn4.innerText;
  btn4.innerText = btn7.innerText;
  btn7.innerText = btn8.innerText;
  btn8.innerText = btn9.innerText;
  btn9.innerText = btn6.innerText;
  btn6.innerText = btn3.innerText;
  btn3.innerText = btn2.innerText;
  btn2.innerText = textofBtn;
});
```

but I saw another solution looking like more elegant here is you can check;

```
let nums=[1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4];
const ids=[1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4];

let btn5=document.getElementById("btn5");

btn5.onclick=function() {
    nums.unshift(nums.pop());
    for (i=0; i<=7; i++) {
        document.getElementById("btn"+ids[i]).innerHTML=nums[i];
    }
}
// writed by mark_russellbro1(hackerrank username)
```